# PHP - Looping through and adding values to array, loop back if end is reached to add remaining values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

First of all, sorry about the title, I didn't know how to explain this in a few words any better.

A similar question has been answered here: [PHP - Rearranging a string into order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318115/php-rearranging-a-string-into-order)

But this (kinda) doesn't work for me.

I have an array with poker players, I already know alot of information about them, like who is at the button. I want to assign different values to all the players based on whos at the button position.

This is what I have made so far, but it's not working as intended:

```
function playerPosition($numplayers, $BTNPlayer, $players) {

    switch ($numplayers) {
        case '3' :
            $gameStates = array("BTN", "SB", "BB");
            break;
        case '4' :
            $gameStates = array("BTN", "SB", "BB", "CO");
            break;
        case '5' :
            $gameStates = array("BTN", "SB", "BB", "MP", "CO");
            break;
        case '6' :
            $gameStates = array("BTN", "SB", "BB", "UTG", "MP", "CO");
            break;
        case '7' :
            $gameStates = array("BTN", "SB", "BB", "UTG", "UTG", "MP", "CO");
            break;
        case '8' :
            $gameStates = array("BTN", "SB", "BB", "UTG", "UTG", "MP", "MP", "CO");
            break;
        case '9' :
            $gameStates = array("BTN", "SB", "BB", "UTG", "UTG", "UTG", "MP", "MP", "CO");
            break;
        case '10' :
            $gameStates = array("BTN", "SB", "BB", "UTG", "UTG", "UTG", "MP", "MP", "MP", "CO");
            break;
    }
    $looped = false;
    $found = false;
    $foundAt = 0;
    $c = 0;

    for ($x = 0; $x < count($players); $x++) {

        if($players[$x]['name'] == $BTNPlayer && !$found) {
            $players[$x]['position'] = $gameStates[$c];
            $found = true;
            $foundAt = $x;

        } else {
            if($found) {
                if ($x != $foundAt)
                    $players[$x]['position'] = $gameStates[$c++];
            }

            if ($found && !$looped) {
                $x = -1;
                $looped = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return $players;
}

$players = array(array('seat' => '1','name' => 'Player1', 'stack' => '2.68', 'status' => '1'), 
                 array('seat' => '2','name' => 'Player2', 'stack' => '7.23', 'status' => '1'), 
                 array('seat' => '3','name' => 'Player3', 'stack' => '0.00', 'status' => '0'), 
                 array('seat' => '4','name' => 'Player4', 'stack' => '1.03', 'status' => '1'), 
                 array('seat' => '5','name' => 'Player5', 'stack' => '0.63', 'status' => '1'), 
                 array('seat' => '6','name' => 'Player6', 'stack' => '1.23', 'status' => '1'), 
                 array('seat' => '7','name' => 'Player7', 'stack' => '2.24', 'status' => '1'), 
                 array('seat' => '8','name' => 'Player8', 'stack' => '3.47', 'status' => '1'), 
                 array('seat' => '9','name' => 'Player9', 'stack' => '5.04', 'status' => '1')
                );

$BTNPlayer = 'Player4';
$positions = playerPosition(9, $BTNPlayer, $players);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($positions);
```

This Results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [seat] => 1
            [name] => Player1
            [stack] => 2.68
            [status] => 1
            [position] => SB
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [seat] => 2
            [name] => Player2
            [stack] => 7.23
            [status] => 1
            [position] => BB
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [seat] => 3
            [name] => Player3
            [stack] => 0.00
            [status] => 0
            [position] => UTG
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [seat] => 4
            [name] => Player4
            [stack] => 1.03
            [status] => 1
            [position] => BTN
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [seat] => 5
            [name] => Player5
            [stack] => 0.63
            [status] => 1
            [position] => UTG
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [seat] => 6
            [name] => Player6
            [stack] => 1.23
            [status] => 1
            [position] => UTG
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [seat] => 7
            [name] => Player7
            [stack] => 2.24
            [status] => 1
            [position] => MP
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [seat] => 8
            [name] => Player8
            [stack] => 3.47
            [status] => 1
            [position] => MP
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [seat] => 9
            [name] => Player9
            [stack] => 5.04
            [status] => 1
            [position] => CO
        )
)
```

As you can see, the sorting function isn't working as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should generate the desired result:

```
function playerPosition($BTNPlayer, $players) {
    $gameStates = array("BTN", "SB", "BB", "UTG", "UTG", "UTG", "MP", "MP", "MP", "CO");
    if(count($players) > count($gameStates))
        throw new Exception('Max player number' .count($gameStates));

    //first find the player
    $btnPlayerIndex = getPlayerIndexByName($BTNPlayer, $players);

    //now we change the array so we start with the btn player
    $sortedPlayers = array_merge(
        array_slice($players, $btnPlayerIndex),
        array_slice($players, 0, $btnPlayerIndex)
    );

    //now we assign your game states
    foreach($sortedPlayers AS $index => &$player){
        $player['position'] = $gameStates[$index];
    }
    return $sortedPlayers;
    }

function getPlayerIndexByName($BTNPlayer, $players){
    foreach($players AS $index => $player){
        if($player['name'] == $BTNPlayer) return $index;
    }
    return false;
}

$players = array(array('seat' => '1','name' => 'Player1', 'stack' => '2.68', 'status' => '1'),
    array('seat' => '2','name' => 'Player2', 'stack' => '7.23', 'status' => '1'),
    array('seat' => '3','name' => 'Player3', 'stack' => '0.00', 'status' => '0'),
    array('seat' => '4','name' => 'Player4', 'stack' => '1.03', 'status' => '1'),
    array('seat' => '5','name' => 'Player5', 'stack' => '0.63', 'status' => '1'),
    array('seat' => '6','name' => 'Player6', 'stack' => '1.23', 'status' => '1'),
    array('seat' => '7','name' => 'Player7', 'stack' => '2.24', 'status' => '1'),
    array('seat' => '8','name' => 'Player8', 'stack' => '3.47', 'status' => '1'),
    array('seat' => '9','name' => 'Player9', 'stack' => '5.04', 'status' => '1')
);

$BTNPlayer = 'Player5';
$positions = playerPosition($BTNPlayer, $players);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($positions);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! And a much more elegant way to do it :)